# optional match doesn't work as expected in Neo4j 2.0.0

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have users in my graphdb and they are voting to brands. I have a case which I need to find the users that don't vote any brand. I prepare a console view you can play with. I need to take 'Trinity' named node, in this console example;

[Console Example](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=gqkz7f)

Tried optional match without luck.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to match all nodes that do not have a particular relationship? Like `MATCH (n:User) WHERE NOT n-[:Voted]->() ...`?

Comment: Oh my god, is that really simple? Thanks jjaderberg that's exactly what I wanted. I tried that before like this: `MATCH (n:User) WHERE NOT n-[:Voted]->(b:Brand)` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way with optional match is more cumbersome (but potentially faster):

```
MATCH (n:User)  
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:Voted]->(brand) 
WITH n,brand 
WHERE brand IS NULL 
RETURN n, brand
```

As the `WHERE` belongs internally to the `optional match` (like in sql `join ON (...)`) so it can be used to specify constraints that the optional match will adhere to.

So if you want to filter the "results" of the optional matching you have to separate that with `WITH`.

Comment: I cannot figure out optional-with-where. When I remove first match from query it doesn't work. If I remove 'with', again no success. But it can still find brand. This optional match confusing me. Can you explain a bit more.